# Longest distance Kinect can take

Tags: kinect

I am planning a project using Kinect's depth sensoring but I do not have a Kinect yet.

Newest information from Microsoft's website says it can take **over 4m**, and Wikipedia page says **over 6m**. What I want is **about 20m**, is that OK for Kinect? If not what is the bottleneck, SDK or hardware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error will increase dramatically as you go farther out. At 20m, I don't think you'd get anywhere near the quality you need to run any kind of application reliably. Keep in mind that the resolution of the camera is only 640×480 pixels. Things farther away are smaller, and harder to discern. It's a hardware limitation. You will likely find it very difficult to use if you're expecting results at 20 meters.

See [this blog post](http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/12/limitations-of-kinect.html) for more information about the limitations.